# Rscript does not recognize previously created variables

Tags: r, rscript

I am preparing some Rscript automation and when running below 3 R-files with Rscript command (in a terminal) I get the following error after running [result.R]:

```
Error: object 'a' not found
Execution halted.
```

I do check in R terminal that Rscript has created the variables [a] and [b], so it seems to be that when running the final Rscript, it does not recognize that the variables has been created in R.

I am running Linux Ubuntu 16.04 with R version 3.4.4.
All files are stored in the same folder.

Below is the content of my R scripts:

```
#File: a.R
# Content:
a <- 1
save.image ('.RData')

#File: b.R
# Content:
b <- 2
save.image ('.RData')

#File: result.R
# Content: 
load('.RData')
c = a + b
save.image('.RData')
```

**Scenario that works:**

If I create the variables [a] and [b] in R terminal, and then run the result.R with Rscript, it does not throw an error message.

Comment: It looks like you are overwriting '.RData' and not appending to it in `b.R`. If you add `load('.RData')` in `b.R` I think you would be good to go.

Comment: @emilliman5 Your suggestion works. If you move your comment into an answer I will accept the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a `load('.RData')` to `b.R`. To prevent overwriting the objects from `a.R`.

```
#File: a.R
# Content:
a <- 1
save.image('.RData')

#File: b.R
# Content:
load('.RData')
b <- 2
save.image('.RData')

#File: result.R
# Content: 
load('.RData')
c = a + b
save.image('.RData')
```